# Реверс хэш-функции

Tags: c++, хеширование, reverse-engineering

Есть функция хэшировния строки c символами A-Za-z0-9_. Как её обратить, чтобы можно было перебирать строки с одинаковым хэшем? Иными словами, нужно написать что-то наподобие генератора строк (до 15000) с одинаковым хэшем.

```
const int p = 31;
size_t operator()(const string& s) const {
    size_t hash = 0, p_pow = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        hash += (s[i] - 'a' + 1) * p_pow;
        p_pow *= p;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что обычно при хэшировании теряется некоторое кол-во информации и обратное преобразование не является однозначным?

Comment: Ну конкретно ту это даже не хеш, а представление слова в 31-разрядной системе (если буквы только маленькие латинские)

Comment: @AlexeyTen - точно, снова забыл уточнить про формат строк: латинский алфавит в обоих регистрах, цифры и нижнее подчёркивание

Comment: @CrazyElf - да, но мне нужна генерация строк по заданному хэшу, а не восстановление конкретной строки

Comment: Так, ну если это хэш обратимый и взаимо однозначный, то что тогда такое "генератор строк с одинаковым хэшем", ведь тогда не будет двух строк с одним хэшем или я опять не так понял?

Comment: Судя по алфавиту он не взаимо-однозначный, но вариантов мало и они легко вычислимы. Это ж обычный полином

Comment: Уберите слово хэш из вопроса. Это никакой не хэш (в стандартном понимании) и вы только вводите всех в заблуждение

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, это скорее просто кодирование или как это правильно назвать

Comment: О, тут ещё и отрицательные числа получаются. На кой вообще эта упячка существует…

Comment: Да, числа отрицательные, которые записываются в unsigned, а потом к нему может быть что-то прибавлено/убавлено и ещё домножено, и, в общем, это вообще не полином, как его представляют Сумма(S[i]*p^i)

Comment: @Eraston, вы хотите по заданному хэшу (для сомневающихся: то, что считает данный код **называется хэшем** (хэши бывают разные, но тут разговор не об этом)) получить одну строку (набор байт) или заданное количество разных строк? Кстати,  есть ли какие-то ограничения на символы этих строк (да и сами строки (префиксы-суффиксы, повторы символов и т.п.)?

Comment: @avp набор строк до 15000 штук, длины до 16 символов, включающие символы A-Za-z0-9_ в любом порядке и любом количестве. И да, это хэш-функция, там и название переменной "hash", и не мной это придумано =.=

Comment: Да я не сомневаюсь что это хэш-функция (формально хэшом можно хоть  x=>x обозвать), но обычно под этим понимают более узкий класс функций.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, кроме тупого перебора рандомных строк мне ничего в голову не приходит. Но, вполне вероятно, тут есть значительно более продвинутые в математике люди

Comment: Кстати, я тут заметил, что последовательность  символов `Aa` даёт `0` так что её можно дописывать справа к любому ответу

Comment: Ох, хотя тут у вас беззнаковый size_t, так что не очень понимаю что с ним происходит при попытке сохранять в него отрицательные числа

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш «хэш» это просто полином вида S = a<sub>n</sub>×31<sup>n</sup> + … + a<sub>1</sub>×31 + a<sub>0</sub>.

Где все a<sub>k</sub> имеют значения из списка `-48…-39` (0-9), `-31…-6` (A-Z), `-1` (_) и `1…26` (a-z).

Для примера возьмём S = 20.
Посчитаем остаток от деления на 31. `S % 31 = 20`. (Ну да, немножко тривиально).
Очевидно что a<sub>k</sub> при k >= 1 никак не влияют на этот остаток. Смотрим какие значения a<sub>0</sub> могут дать такой остаток. Это значения `20`, `-11` и `-42`. Т.е. первый символ нашей строки это `t`, `U` или `6`.

не дописал…

Comment: Может, я могу понять то, что вы написали, но не совсем понимаю, от чего искать остаток от деления, и что он показывает. Но с этим можно разобраться. Другой вопрос, что 31^14 > 2^64...
Но попробую сделать что-то с тем, о чём вы написали

Comment: Посчитайте хеши от `t`, `Ua` и `6b`. Если я правильно понимаю код, то они будут одинаковые.

Comment: Да, одинаковые.

Comment: @Eraston берете хеш, считаете остаток от деления на 31, находите первый символ. Вычитаете из хеша этот остаток, делите полученную разность на 31 и опять ищете остаток от деления на 31. Получаете второй символ и т.д.. Когда в результате очередного вычитания получаете 0 - строка найдена. Если получаете отрицательное число, то прибавляете к нему 2^64

Comment: Вот только ТС хочет получить не одну подходящую строку, а 15000. Как тут сделать "направленную" генерацию?

Comment: @avp так это и есть алгоритм направленной генерации. Ну не бывает у этого «хэша» 15000 коллизий.

Comment: @AlexeyTen [23105](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Zbm3WQtYeD8YXqNf9GR3YQhQLsJ2Lnz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Eraston а там точно ошибок округления нет?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, если строки длинные-длинные, то у любого хэша (и из семейста SHA тоже) будет очень много возможных коллизий. Заметьте, я не говорю о *реальной возможности* найти их для криптографических хэшей

Comment: @AlexeyTen может и есть, но вычисляемый хэш для строк по этой функции совпадает

Answer (score 0):

В общем, выросло следующее. Не уверен, что приведённый код перебирает **все** доступные строки заданной длины, но может генерировать некоторое множество строк с одинаковым хэшем.

```
void recursiveSearch( size_t hash, std::string s ){
    if( hash == 0 ){
        // Строка найдена
        // ...
        return;
    }
    if( s.size() < 12 ) // Ограничить размер строки, иначе некая бесконечная строка может иметь ненулевой хэш
        for( auto q : ab ) // Для каждого символа алфавита
        {
            if( ( hash - q ) % 31 == 0 ) // Если символ подходящий
                // Искать подпоследовательность(-и)
                recursiveSearch( ( hash - q ) / 31, s + std::string( 1, static_cast<char>( q + 'a' - 1 ) ) );
        }
}
```

Группа вывода:

> OPHRBCBBBBBBBBa
> OPHRBCBBBBBBBa
> OPHRBCBBBBBBa
> OPHRBCBBBBBa
> OPHRBCBBBBa
> OPHRBCBBBa
> OPHRBCBBa
> OPHRBCBa
> OPHRBCa
> OPHRBb

Comment: К сожалению, исходной поставленной задачи это не решает, в которой в std::unordered_set нужно добавить 15000 строк таких, чтобы время работы программы превысило 1,5 секунды, - по логике устройства хэш-таблицы, самый очевидный способ, добавлять те строки, хэш которых совпадает